# How limit one click for new textContent button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Currently, clicking a button and fadeOut can be clicked many times.

I want the user to only be able to click once for new text button.  Because clicking more than once causes a bug in my code.

I tried to use `.one()`, but when new text button fadeIn the click does not work - because the button is same object, only the `textContent` has changed.

How do I limit to one click for each new `textContent` on a button?

```js
let clickNumber = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().text("B")
  })
  $("p").text(clickNumber++)
})

/*$("button").one("click", function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().text("B")
  })
  $("p").text(clickNumber++)
})*/
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add a boolean and check if it is active

```js
let clickNumber = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
  const btn = $(this);
  if (btn.data('active')) return;
  btn.data('active', true);
  $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().text("B")
    // btn.data('active', false); If you want them to click it again
  })
  $("p").text(clickNumber++)
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on` an `off` events of the button, and if you don´t need the click count you can avoid it so you can have simpler code:

```js
$('#option1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).off('click');
  $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn().text("B");
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, having a button that can be clicked but does nothing is not good UX as the user will spam click it and get annoyed / accidently click it when it changes (when it appears you want click re-enabled given the statement *but when new text button fadeIn the click is not working*)

While you can use css

```css
  pointer-events: none;
```

it generally doesn't have a very good UI.  While a combination of `disabled` to stop it being clicked and `cursor: not-allowed;` to show it can't be clicked helps to make it clear to the user what's happening.

```js
let clickNumber = 0;

$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).prop("disabled", "disabled").addClass("noclick");

  $(this).fadeOut(3000, function() {

    $(this)
      .text("B")
      .prop("disabled", null)
      .removeClass("noclick")
      .fadeIn();
  });

  // demo just to see it being clicked, has no impact of if it can be clicked
  $("p").text(++clickNumber)
})
```

```css
.noclick {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
  <p></p>
</div>
```